# Python-mode: maintain indentation before closing brace?

Tags: indentation, python

Python's style guide ([PEP 8: Indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)) suggests two alternatives for indenting the close paren for a multi-line function call.

```
some_function(
    first_long_argument,
    second_long_argument,
    )
```

or

```
some_function(
    first_long_argument,
    second_long_argument,
)
```

I'm getting the second style (with Emacs 24.5.1) with `M-x indent-region` but would like to know how to customize my .emacs configuration to get the first. I would like the first indentation to also result from tabbing the line with ')', as right now it remains unindented.

Comment: Please re-read the question and make sure that you have the "first" and "second" straight. Right now it looks like you typed "second" meaning "first" in some places.

Comment: @Constantine Thanks, I straightened myself out.

Answer (score 1):

With python-mode.el, that would be `py-closing-list-dedents-bos`.
Sorry, can't answer that WRT built-in python.el